# Changing Clock Font Colour in GTK 2.0 Theme

Tags: xubuntu, themes, colors

I installed the [Flattastic Blue Light](http://nale12.deviantart.com/art/Flattastic-11-03-2014-424913255) theme and now I am looking for a way to change the font color of my clock in the panel.

[image: the light blue clock, next to my battery icon]

I already tried changing the font color in my GTK-2.0 configuration file (panel), but that only affects the Username and not the clock.

I am running Xubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to the question myself, since I stumbled upon the file ~/.gtkrc-2.0 that was only for the configuration of my panel clock.

```
  style "panel-clock-custom"
  {
  fg[NORMAL]    = "#585a5c"
  fg[PRELIGHT]    = "#585a5c"
  fg[ACTIVE]    = "#585a5c"
  text[NORMAL]    = "#585a5c"
  text[PRELIGHT]    = "#585a5c"
  text[ACTIVE]    = "#585a5c"
  }
  widget "Xfce*Panel*clock*"    style "panel-clock-custom"
```

I simply changed all the hex values to my desired color.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the program Gpick to mouse over the clock to get the specific hexadecimal color. Gpick is in the repositories if it is not already installed. (This might not work if when you mouseover you are getting a lot of different hexadecimal results.)

Next you can do the following:

Go into your theme folder:

```
cd /usr/share/themes/Flattastic-Blue-Light
```

Next search all files with that same color:

```
grep -R 000000
```

Above, replace 000000 with your hexadecimal color.

This is not a complete answer, but perhaps it can get you started in finding what needs changing. It was a little too much to put in a comment.

I also did notice this color, `#4fc0e8`, on line 4 of:

```
/usr/share/themes/Flattastic-Blue-Light/gtk-2.0/gtkrc
```

This color seems very similar to the color of the clock. However, changing that will likely change other elements as well.

To make any change go into effect, I recommend going to Appearance in your menu and toggling between your theme and another one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I fixed it myself. I could change the color of the panel clock in a hidden file in my home folder, which I didn't see before.

Comment: @lenala I am glad to see that you found the solution. I love it when I am finally able to get all the last details of my theme just right. I see that you marked my answer as the correct one. I actually recommend adding an answer to your own question with all of the details of what you did to resolve the issue so others could benefit from it as well. Then I would mark your own answer as the correct one given that it was actually the solution you needed.